# What is defferent between CNI and CNI plugin?

Tags: containerd, cni

I am exploring [CNI](https://github.com/containernetworking) on Github for using containerd and see they have 2 repos there

[CNI](https://github.com/containernetworking/cni)   and   [CNI Plugin](https://github.com/containernetworking/plugins)  with different version numbers.

I got a bit confused about the differences between them and where / when should use each of them? Are they the samething or not?

Comment: My reading of the README files is that CNI contains the libraries that can be used to implement plugins and CNI Plugins contains "example" or "reference" plugins that perform various tasks.  Also read what is available on https://www.cni.dev/

Comment: I am from windows world and now working on linux with these opensource things, my understanding from the "name" itself, sounds like CNI just like an individule software which I can install on my Windows machine (for example) and CNI plgin is an add-on to another existing software/system, just like an add-on to Chrome browser sort of concept?

Comment: I don't think that your "Windows understanding" applies here.   You should read the actual words of the README files and try to understand what they actually say.  CNI is not an "individual software".  That's not what the README plainly says.   Anyway, I'm not here to debate it with you.